# React-Native upgrade for iOS: options

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

- I am planning to upgrade the react-native from 0.51 to 0.62 for the iOS platform. Typically what is the duration it takes for an upgrade?
- Can I carry out a staggered upgrade? Just to upgrade the react-native to the latest version and libraries to be upgraded later.
- I can live with deprecated API if it doesn't break existing functionality or doesn't have performance issues.

Which is a better way: one version at a time or one portion of code at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible way is:
Copy and create a new repository(git master).
and carry out a direct upgrade to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more insights about amount of work that's in front of you with upgrade helper: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.51.0&to=0.62.0